# Upgraded to Mavericks, C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: ruby, xcode, gcc

Upgrading to Mavericks, I *appear* to have broken my Ruby on Rails development environment, which requires ruby 1.9.3 because of various gem dependencies. Within that app directory, I'm trying to reinstall ruby 1.9.3-p547:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p547
```

I then get an error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/dsfaulkenberry/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p547':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Looking at the config.log file (~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p547/config.log), I see:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/cloog-ppl015/lib/libcloog.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc46/4.6.4/gcc/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0/4.6.4/cc1
  Reason: image not found
```

I can see that other people have encountered issues vis-à-vis upgrading to Mavericks and having c compiler issues, but I can't find any referencing this specific library or what I should do (reinstall gcc? is that even a thing I can do?)

Many solutions mention accepting an XCode license agreement, which I have done, and the problem persists.

A Stack Overflow user suggested uninstalling gcc through homebrew which I have done to no avail, and another user has suggested reinstalling homebrew itself, which I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Command Line tools (gcc goodies) do not come installed with Mavericks (insert bad word here). You need to download the latest and great xcode, go into the xcode prefs and install the command line tools (I believe it's under General). You should be right as rain.

Or! I noticed this trick: [Installing Command Line Tools](http://www.computersnyou.com/2025/2013/06/install-command-line-tools-in-osx-10-9-mavericks-how-to/)

Comment: The weird thing is, my problem went away on it's own.  I don't know why or how.  System reboot?  Installed a seemingly unrelated gem?

Comment: LOL Not sure. Glad it's solved! Go ahead and close the Q/A then =)